# Is there a way to debug/interrogate a COM assembly that my .NET application is calling via interop?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I am calling an old (ca 2014) COM assembly in a .NET application.  The system that this application is running on has been moved from one domain to another, and apparently the COM assembly requires settings or some other values that are present in the profile, so we moved/copied profile data over to the new domain users profile.  This has fixed a number of issues concerning the use of this COM assembly, but at least one still remains.  It is attempting to access some file during the execution of a method, and it throws a `The specified path is invalid` exception.

The developer for this tool is no longer available, and what I really need is to just find out what file it is trying to access, and get that file back into the filesystem where it is looking for it.  The documentation is not helpful in this regard.

Comment: Look at the file activity in [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @dxiv That is exactly what I did next, actually, thanks!  I have not found the problem yet, but Process Monitor has netted me a TON of potential files that may be the problem.  Ill have to go through them tomorrow to see what the case is.

Comment: ProcMon has pretty powerful filters & highlights to help narrow it down. Good luck with the debugging.